# Tab spacing in align environment?

Tags: align

How can I achieve this?

```
Example 1:        a = b         b = c

Example 2:        this equation is way longer than the others

Example 1:        c = d         e = f
```

All three lines are in a single `align` environment, but I can't manage to get it right, using `&&` I always get

```
Example 1:        a = b                                             b = c

Example 2:        this equation is way longer than the others

Example 1:        c = d                                             e = f
```

because of the long second equation?

My code:

```
\begin{align*}

& Example 1: && a = b && b = c \\

& Example 2: && \text{this equation is way longer than the others} \\

& Example 1: && c = d && e = f

\end{align*}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are three possibilities, either with `align*`  or with `alignat*` (to have full control on the columns spacing. Also, I think, it would look better if the align environment started at the left margin, which can be done locally with the `fleqn`  environment from `nccmath`. Furthermore, the distance from the left margin where the environment starts can be set as an optional argument of `fleqn`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nccmath, mathtools}

\begin{document}

\noindent Some text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text.
\begin{align*}
& \text{Example 1:} && a = b && b = c \\
&\text{Example 2:} && \mathrlap{this equation is way longer than the others} \\
& \text{Example 3:} && c = d && e = f
\end{align*}
\vskip 1cm
\begin{fleqn}
\begin{align*}
& \text{Example 1:} && a = b && b = c \\
&\text{Example 2:} && \mathrlap{this equation is way longer than the others} \\
& \text{Example 3:} && c = d && e = f
\end{align*}
\end{fleqn}
\vskip 1cm
\begin{fleqn}[1em]
\begin{alignat*}{3}
& \text{Example 1:} &\qquad& a = b &\hspace{5em}& b = c \\
&\text{Example 2:} && \mathrlap{this equation is way longer than the others} \\
& \text{Example 3:} && c = d && e = f
\end{alignat*}
\end{fleqn}
 Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Since the OP [indicated that the long stuff is actually math stuff](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/517575/tab-spacing-in-align-environment#comment1308917_517581), probably the OP will want to use `\mathrlap` command from `mathtools` instead of standard `rlap`.

Comment: @WillieWong: You're absolutely right. I was confused by the fact  the O.P. wrote actually text. Thanks for reminding me!

Answer (score 1):

[Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) The `align*` environment is best used for aligning equations, rather than text (in your case, the words "Example" will not be typeset as text, but rather as math symbols). Perhaps using the `align` (without `*`) environment is more suitable for referring to your equations later, as that numbers each line.

If you really want to put both together, I suggest using `tabular` and `\multicolumn`:

```
\begin{tabular}{r c c}
Example 1: & $a=b$ & $b=c$ \\
Example 2: & \multicolumn{2}{c}{this equation is way longer than the others}\\
Example 3: & $c=d$ & $e=f$
\end{tabular}
```

This is the result:

[image]

The [`\intertext`](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Advanced_Mathematics#Text_in_aligned_math_display) command may also be useful, if you want to break an `align` environment but remember the alignment.

Comment: thanks, but i really need the align command, since the text "this equation..." really is a long equation. If a use several align commands, the vertical spacing between these is too large and also the equations in lines "Example 1: .." and "Example 3: ..." are not horizontally aligned anymore.

Comment: \mathrlap works perfectly!
thanks a lot!